# supremum and infimum of set $\left\{ \frac{nk}{1+2n+3k} : n,k \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

First of all, I can't use limits. I need to use $0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_{0}$ method.

So when $n=1$, I get $\frac{k}{3+3k} = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3(1+k)}$

and we all know that for very large k the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$ so because $0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_{0}$, let $k = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Then we have $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+1)} > \frac{1}{3} - \epsilon$

$-\frac{1}{3(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+1)} > - \epsilon$

$-\frac{1}{3} > -\epsilon\ (\frac{1}{\epsilon}+1)$

$\frac{1}{3} < 1 + \epsilon$

$ \epsilon > -\frac{2}{3} $ Which is alway true since $0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_{0}$

Thus $\frac{1}{3} = sup A$

So few questions:

- since $k \in \mathbb{N}$ can I say $k = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ ?
- "and we all know that for very large k the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$" how can i put this is mathematical language? Or is it okey to leave it how it is?

Answer (score 0):

I think the sup is $\infty$. Try dividing by just n and letting n to infinity. You are left with k / 2, which can be as large as you like.

The inf is 1/6 ? (n=k=1)

Comment: Uh, you are right with supA. How to show that supA=infinity?

Comment: For $n=k>1,$ we have $\dfrac{nk}{1+2n+3k}>\dfrac{n^2}{n+2n+3n}=\dfrac{n}{6}$ which is unbounded, therefore $\sup$ does not exist.